# jquery counting inside input with custom value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic counter that counts up within an input field. this works exactly how I want it to. The problem I am facing is that I can only set the target number via the input value. i want to be able to set this via a js variable, ignoring the html input value

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/vyN6V/238/

Current jQuery

```
  var number = 827;

    function count(Item){
        var current = parseInt(Item.val());
        Item.val(current +=5);
        if(current < number){
            setTimeout(function(){count(Item)}, 0.1);
        }
    }        
    count($(".input"));
```

Desired jQuery (doesn't work)

```
  var number = 827;
  var aValue = 500;

    function count(Item){
        var current = aValue;
        Item.val(current +=5);
        if(current < number){
            setTimeout(function(){count(Item)}, 0.1);
        }
    }        
    count($(".input"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should work, you just forgot to add 5 to aValue:

```
    var current = aValue;
    aValue+=5;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current is inside your function, it works if you simply use `aValue`:

```
Item.val(aValue += 5);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyN6V/239/)

Answer (score 0):

this would solve the problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/Jg6LN/1/

```
var number = 827;
  var aValue = 500;

    function count(Item, value){
        var current = value || parseInt(Item.val());
        Item.val(current +=5);
        if(current < number){
            setTimeout(function(){count(Item)}, 0.1);
        }
    }        
    count($(".input"), aValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
var aValue = 500;
var number = 827;

function count(Item) {
    var current = parseInt(Item.val()) || aValue;
    Item.val(current + 5);

    if (Item.val() < number) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            count(Item)
        }, 0.1);
    }
}

count($(".input"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vyN6V/242/